# Datagrid ActualHeight without column header height

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to get the ActualHeight of a WPF Datagrid without considering the column header height.
[image]

How to get that? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by accessing the `DataGridRowsPresenter` of the `DataGrid`. Like,

```
var dataGridRowsPresenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridRowsPresenter>(grid);
double actualHeight = dataGridRowsPresenter.ActualHeight;
```

Method to find Visual Child of a `control`:

```
public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (current == null) return null;
    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
        if (child is T) return (T)child;
        T result = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: DataGridRowsPresenter, that was it! Thank you very much